# What is the cache miss rate for an optimal matrix transpose?

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, memory-management, cpu-cache

If I have an `M` x `N` matrix and an L1 cache of size K what cache miss rate does an optimal matrix transpose have. Obviously I am looking for something that is a function of `M` and `N` (and possibly `K`, though that is maybe too complex) rather than a specific number.

I am asking because I have a lot of matrix data that has to be processed in both directions and I would like a rule of thumb to know when it is worth while keeping both the original data and a transpose in memory.

Comment: The definition of a cache-miss becomes a little fuzzy when you factor in prefetching and cache-lines.

Comment: For example, does a successful prefetch count as a cache-miss? Does an access to an already-in-progress fetch count as another cache miss?

Comment: Well, is there a reasonable rule of thumb for when it is faster to create both a matrix and its transpose in memory, I suppose that is what I am really after.

Comment: Depending on the granularity of the transpose, the optimal method can require multiple copies. Although even a naive transpose will perform reasonably well since the hardware does a pretty good job of hiding the latencies. The only "tricks" that really work well are the ones that optimize for the cache-line. Manual prefetching also helps when done properly.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I didn't state that clearly. I'm not asking whether _doing_ the transpose requires multiple copies, I'm asking about the situation where I have to do, say, a lot of processing of a lot of pretty large matrices. Some of that processing is along rows. Other stages are along columns. Because of this one might be tempted transpose the matrix every time one switches between row ops and column ops (or just create transpose once if processing doesn't alter values), but one would like an idea of how much an efficient large matrix transpose "costs" to decide whether this is a good idea.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that the most efficient way to do a large transpose is to do multiple copies. There's a trade-off where you can reduce the amount of strided-access by doing more copies. In any case, a transpose is still generally considered a very expensive operation. I can't say whether it will be worth it in your case, but an optimal transpose is fairly hard to implement and requires very careful tuning that is sensitive to the system it is running on.

Comment: Yah, that is why I just wanted "rule of thumb". Right now, I have access to intels MKL, which I am assuming uses a decent transpose, but I probably won't always have access to that so I didn't include it in my question.

Comment: I wouldn't know. I've never really tried to seriously optimize a transpose since I don't need them much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said anything about the cache type you have, is it direct mapped? N-way set associative? Assuming a N-way set associative (and yes you do need all the details of the cache that depends on your specific CPU architecture) and assuming one specific matrix ordering e.g. column-major then you will have mostly cold misses basically M*N/C where C is the cache line size (which is CPU dependent but usually 8 doubles :)).

Then you will have stridded accesses on the target matrix and this unless the matrix is small enough to fit entirely in L1 you can assume a worst-case scenario of M*N cold misses e.g. an L1 of size 32kB you can fit 4000 doubles i.e. a matrix of size ~63*63.

Therefore we would be looking at a worst-case (M*N/C + M*N) total L1 misses for the transposition.

One idea would be to do the trick of flipping the matrix ordering e.g. from column-major to row-major, instead of physically moving it, **access it as transposed**. This is a zero cost operation if you have the right matrix implementation where you could flip the matrix ordering on the same data.

The real expensive prefetches though are never at L1 but at the LLC (last level cache) even if you get L1 misses it is still a cheap miss because it will be loaded from L2. In conclusion it is very hard to calculate unless you have all the tiny small details of your target CPU archirecture.

Comment: +1 for the modified access pattern - i'd like to know how useful/common that is

Comment: the degree of usefulness depends on what the dominant access pattern on the target transposed matrix is. You are free to choose the ordering of the source and target matrices to match the operations access pattern in both cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  For a cache in which each line holds K doubles, you need at least N^2 / K cache misses to do the job.  Doesn't the divide-and-conquer transpose algorithm come very, very close to attaining this on any matrix size that lets me have the same column for K consecutive rows in cache simultaneously?

Comment: You need *at most* (M*N/K) cold misses assuming you are iterating the matrix with memory-adjacent accesses i.e. every time you access an element, the next K-1 will be available in the cache line and will be a cache hit. OTOH when you iterate the target matrix with non memory-adjacent accesses every access is a cold miss, therefore the cache miss rate is going to be N*M

Comment: I said at most because if the matrix is small where there are overlapping accesses then you will be doing less than (M*N/K).

Comment: But I should be able to cover up the latency added by the cold misses by prefetching since my access pattern is *very* predictable.  Assuming the input is square, I need to fetch N^2 / K lines from memory into cache during the execution of my matrix transpose, and I don't see why anything other than L1 really matters here unless you're trying to bound the execution time using throughput from memory to cache.

Comment: I mean the true cache misses are in the last level cache exactly from RAM to LLC cache. The misses that lead to copying from L2 to L1 don't really matter much. The cost in cycles for L2 -> L1 is negligible compared to RAM -> LLC something like 1 to 100.

Comment: The *latency* of a RAM -> LLC fetch is huge.  But it's also effectively hidden with prefetching, so the actual performance cost of those misses should be zero if the transpose is designed correctly.  Right?  So, at worst, you're bound by the *bandwidth* of the bus between the LLC and the RAM, right?

Comment: Accessing it as transposed isn't free because, for example, if the matrix is in row major order and you are doing heavy computations on some column then you have lots and lots of L1 cache misses that wouldn't happen if it had been in column major order. In fact, it is exactly understanding when the cache misses one has from the matrix being in the "wrong" order for what you want makes it worth the hit one takes to transpose the matrix that made me ask this question. I have some stages of processing for which row major is bad, and some for which column major is bad.

Comment: That's correct. But if you transpose only to make one time access then it would make sense to avoid the transposition, depending on what kind of reuse the single access is going to be like. If the operation to make on the transpose has potentially a lot of reuse then it would make sense to take the cost of transposing hoping to amortize it with the potential good reuse.